# Delete statement is taking long time

Tags: db2

I am trying to Delete 1 record from a Parent table (TAB_A with Primary Key as **COL_A**) in DB2 10.5. This table has many child table, but the data is already deleted from Child tables. Due to the foreign key constraint one of the Child Table (TAB_B) Index Scan (IDX1_TAB_B) taking high cost. TAB_B has the composite index on (IDX1_TAB_B = COL_C + **COL_A**). Attaching the executing plan below:

Optimizer Plan:

```
                                                                                                                 Rows
                                                                                                               Operator
                                                                                                                 (ID)
                                                                                                                 Cost

                                                                                                                0.04
                                                                                                               FILTER
                                                                                                                ( 2)
                                                                                                               1450.45
                 +-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+
                  1                      1.66864             1.07095                                   0                           6.30251               1.26543                   25.0657                        1
               DELETE                    IXSCAN              IXSCAN                                  FETCH                         IXSCAN                IXSCAN                    IXSCAN                      IXSCAN
                ( 3)                      ( 5)                ( 6)                                   ( 7)                           ( 9)                  (10)                      (11)                        (12)
               22.7049                   22.7038             **1344.45**                               0.0107876                       15.1445               22.7036                   7.58684                     15.1433
          /---/       \                    |                   |                             /----/         \                        |                     |                         |                           |
      1             6.91522e+06       6.56409e+06            75669                      0                       0                1.01318e+06           4.86182e+06                  213                     1.66563e+06
   IXSCAN         Table:            Index:               Index:                         IXSCAN           Table:                 Index:               Index:                 Index:                      Index:
    ( 4)          GEXPDBA           GEXPUSRT             GEXPDBA                         ( 8)            GEXPDBA                GEXPUSRT             GEXPUSRT               GEXPDBA                     GEXPDBA
   15.1415        TAB_A             IX6_XXXXXXXXXXXX     **IDX1_TAB_B**                    0.0105474         TZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ  IX1_LLLLLLLLLLLLLLL  IX1_LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO  IX1_LOCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC  IDX_GE
     |                                                                                 |
 6.91522e+06                                                                           0
```

Index:                                                                         Index:
 GEXPDBA                                                                        GEXPDBA
 IDX_TAB_A                                                                      IDX_ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ

Comment: Have you tried to create an index on `TAB_B(COL_A)`?

Comment: I have created the suggested Index and it made the Delete faster. Thanks a lot Mark.

Answer (score 0):

An index with FK columns not at the beginning of the index column list (i.e. `(..., FKcol1 [, FKcol2, ...])`) often is not so efficient as an index with those FK columns at the beginning of the index column list (i.e. `(FKcol1 [, FKcol2, ...])`), when the child table is involved in the operations requiring joining with its parent table like in the question.
So, the solution was just to create such an index to improve the operation performance (`delete` statement) on the parent table.